# Match array return types with arbitrary number of inputs using generics

Tags: typescript

If a user passes in type `[Iterable<T>]` I want to return type `[T]` and if the user passes in `[Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>]` I want to return type `[T, U]`. I want to continue this for any number of elements in the input array.

Is there a way to define the types for the following function generically so that it will work for any number of inputs rather than continuing to define overloads of the function with increasing numbers of generic?

Here's what I have so far, but of course it only supports up to 5 inputs as defined. Can I make it work for an arbitrary number of inputs?

```
export function linkIterables<T>(
  iterables: [Iterable<T>],
): Iterable<[T]>;
export function linkIterables<T, U>(
  iterables: [Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>],
): Iterable<[T, U]>;
export function linkIterables<T, U, V>(
  iterables: [Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>, Iterable<V>],
): Iterable<[T, U, V]>;
export function linkIterables<T, U, V, W>(
  iterables: [Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>, Iterable<V>, Iterable<W>],
): Iterable<[T, U, V, W]>;
export function linkIterables<T, U, V, W, X>(
  iterables: [Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>, Iterable<V>, Iterable<W>, Iterable<X>],
): Iterable<[T, U, V, W, X]>;
export function* linkIterables<T>(
  iterables: Iterable<Iterable<T>>,
): Iterable<T[]> {
  const iters = [...iterables].map(u => u[Symbol.iterator]());
  while (true) {
    let done = true;
    const results = [];
    for (const iter of iters) {
      const result = iter.next();
      if (!result.done) {
        done = false;
      }
      results.push(result.value);
    }
    if (done) {
      return results;
    }
    yield results;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you fix the implementation here?  Every time I try to test it my runtime hangs; you seem to be creating new iterators at every loop and calling `next()` exactly once on each one.  That's not going to do good things.  If you can't fix it, maybe just remove it and change the function signature to a `declare` so that the question can focus on the typings and not the implementation.

Comment: Blergh, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5ezZN)?  If your iterables aren't all the same length then you will get `undefined` in places that the compiler claims is defined.  Maybe you should just remove the implementation from the question entirely.  I need to sleep now!

Comment: Sorry about the implementation. It should be fixed now. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [mapped types on array and tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to represent the general operation of turning an output tuple type `T` into an input tuple type where at each numeric index `I` in `T` will have a property of type `Iterable<T[I]>`.  Like this:

```
export function linkIterables<T extends any[]>(
  iterables: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }]
): Iterable<T>;
```

Note that wrapping the type of `iterables` in `[...` `]` uses [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax to hint that we want the compiler to interpret `iterables` as a tuple type if possible and not just an array.  Let's try it:

```
const result = linkIterables([
  [1, 2],
  ["a", "b"],
  [true, false],
  [new Date(), new Date()],
  [document, document],
  [null, null]
]);

// const result: Iterable<[number, string, boolean, Date, Document, null]>
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGxmA1gSSgUwE4CGARsjgM4A8AKojgB65gAmZiBYAngNoC6AfAAoAUIkQxchEuQBciLgDpFAbzmYxSdDg5xgiKj1nZ8xUtS6Z+iAL48hASkMSTOanwDcQoaEiwEAKhQ0LCcpSipBETEQ0jJHYykKI0lTcL4AGns45JcqXj5EJUiIBDIoKPxWAF45Hg9RYDg8RAFisFLy7MQdDucyOwLI0XEK+QAHEDIACwFh7K4AZQ4AWyI4ZHlZgihGngE7OzrrIpK1nHlkOABzAQAiAHkAaQBBAE0bg8iAd0mYUmaoPAgHD9QqiUSkMpMBA4RDVAFAw6iVrtPDkEDIKBVGqIxANJotEplWZdXSzPoDMFg5FlVFkdFlaqzeRgehQPY4oa6AQAQlp9PkUJZ-UFMOqwAIyDIOA5iD5GLIYwm0zlUHkADcJUCPpSrIMxFyRf1UVAQHgkCqyDiODAcMgmLK0fLDrqrB4hNSHXSMbDAhgkr0BFxIlwAIxpRAAJh4GVEXBuBBu4ZuRBu0eD8Jw4fFkpwadjLM+iAAIlscHtwwXi6W9nm5FCICAljgwFBw-XG82oLWuGB0cgK33bDwPnjmh66CTPfSQcc2qdzlcBHQ7EJdQB6NeID0qrLOCg9xtEfDh0p4NCXcOrU7scMl3C3uANpstgfIZD8IA)